# assigning list comprehensions, differences

Tags: python, list-comprehension, variable-assignment, python-itertools

Ok guys, I don't use python all that often (yet), and I kinda dived into it hands on.

Can anyone explain what is going on, so I can read about it?
Also, if you think my code can be simplified, please comment on this.

I'm trying to make all combinations of each element from two lists, and then adding 2 set variables to each combination.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['topic1', 'topic2']
>>> b = [{'key':'value'},{'key2':'value2'}]
>>> c = list(itertools.product(a,b))   
>>> c
[('topic', {'key': 'value'}), ('topic', {'key2': 'value2'}), ('topic2', {'key': 'value'}), ('topic2', {'key2': 'value2'})]
```

I need to make lists, however, to be able to extend them in the following step, so:

```
>>> c = [list(tup) for tup in (itertools.product(a,b))]
>>> c
[['topic', {'key': 'value'}], ['topic', {'key2': 'value2'}], ['topic2', {'key': 'value'}], ['topic2', {'key2': 'value2'}]]

>>> d = [2, "/some/folder"]
>>> e = [x.extend(d) for x in c]
>>> e 
[None, None, None, None]
```

What is going on here exactly? Why is e returning None? I can make it work by just evaluating the list comprehension, without assigning it. How come I could assign my list comprehension in c = (tup for tup ...) but not in e?

```
>>> [tuple(x) for x in c]
[('topic', {'key': 'value'}, 2, '/some/folder/'), ('topic', {'key2': 'value2'}, 2, '/some/folder/'), ('topic2', {'key': 'value'}, 2, '/some/folder/'), ('topic2', {'key2': 'value2'}, 2, '/some/folder/')]
>>> c
[['topic', {'key': 'value'}, 2, '/some/folder/'], ['topic', {'key2': 'value2'}, 2, '/some/folder/'], ['topic2', {'key': 'value'}, 2, '/some/folder/'], ['topic2', {'key2': 'value2'}, 2, '/some/folder/']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list.extend` method *mutates* a list in-place, and the return value of the mutation operation is `None`. In other words, `extend` works only by side-effects.

You can use list concatenation instead, if you want to construct a new result from the previous result instead of mutating the previous result.

```
e = [x + d for x in c]
```